# Proof of a probability inequality claim

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I'm reading a paper which makes an assertion of this form with no proof, where $\mu_S$ is a sample mean random variable, $\mu_T$ is a true or population mean r.v, and $\varepsilon$ is a constant:

> For every real number $k \in (0,1)$
>
> $$\Pr[|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{S1}| \geq \varepsilon] \leq \Pr[|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{T}| \geq k \varepsilon] + \Pr[|\mu_{T} - \mu_{S1}| \geq (1-k)\varepsilon]$$

This isn't really obvious to me. How do I prove this, or at least satisfy myself that this is true?

For anyone interested in the source, this is from Bifet & Gavalda 2006. Appendix A Theorem 1.2.

Comment: The event $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{S1}| \geq \epsilon$ is covered by the union of events $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{T}| \geq k\epsilon$ and $|\mu_{T} - \mu_{S1}| \geq (1-k)\epsilon$ (if these both inequalities do not hold, sum up the opposite inequalities and apply triangle inequality), and the probability of union does not exceed the sum of probabilities.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to visualize these events in a Venn diagram sort of way, so I can 'see' that they cover the event $|\mu_S2 - \mu_S1| \geq \epsilon$. 



If we consider $|\mu_S2 - \mu_T| + |\mu_T - \mu_S1| \geq (1-k)\epsilon + \epsilon$

Comment: If we consider the event $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_T| + |\mu_T - \mu_{S1}| \geq (1-k)\epsilon + k\epsilon = \epsilon$, I can see that the union of the events $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_T| > k \epsilon$ and $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_T| > (1-k) \epsilon$ covers this.

Comment: So I suppose since $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_T| + |\mu_T - \mu_{S1}| \geq |\mu_{S2}-\mu_{S1}|$ by the triangle inequality, $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_T| + |\mu_T - \mu_{S1}| \geq \epsilon$ covers $|\mu_{S2}-\mu_{S1}| \geq \epsilon$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it helpful to think about things like this by "translating" events into logical statements, and set operations into logic operation.

Let $A = \{\mu_{S2} - \mu_{S1}| \geq \epsilon\}$, $B = \{|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{T}| \geq k\epsilon\}$ and $C = \{|\mu_{T} - \mu_{S1}| \geq (1-k)\epsilon\}$.  We want to show $A \subseteq B \cup C$, for then we will have $P(A) \le P(B \cup C) \le P(B) \cup P(C)$ by union bound.  The set relation $A \subseteq B \cup C$ is saying "if $A$ then $B$ or $C$".  Ok, well, we know how to prove statements of that form.  In this case it might be easiest to prove the contrapositive "if not $B$ and not $C$ then not $A$" (or in set notation $B^c \cap C^c \subseteq A^c$).

So suppose not $B$ and not $C$, i.e. $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{T}| < k\epsilon$ and $|\mu_{T} - \mu_{S1}| < (1-k)\epsilon$. (More precisely, suppose $\omega \in \Omega$ is such that these two statements hold for $\omega$).  Our goal is to prove not $A$, i.e. to upper bound $|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{S1}|$, and we can clearly see to use the triangle inequality:
$$|\mu_{S2} - \mu_{S1}| \le |\mu_{S2} - \mu_{T}| + |\mu_{T} - \mu_{S1}| < k \epsilon + (1-k)\epsilon = \epsilon$$
which is "not $A$".

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me! 
At present I imagine events as sets of outcomes in nice mental Venn diagrams, so it was useful to see an alternative approach where that sort of visualization might not be possible.

Comment: So a strategy would be to think of outcomes $\omega$ in the sample space $\Omega$ such that some identities of interest hold... Event A represents all outcomes such that  ${\mu_{S2} - \mu_{S1} > \epsilon}$, and similarly for events B and C. Now cut away to Venn diagram thinking; we want to show that $A \subseteq B \cup C$. Then: what statements represent the events in the contrapositive? Then you looked for upper bounds, because A was bounded from above in the contrapositive; and expressed it in terms of identities that figured in the events; and you had a proof.

Comment: What I'm really interested in is how the original author might have come up with this. I'm satisfied with the proof, but how does one "see" the RHS of that inequality from just starting out with $Pr[|\mu_{S2}−\mu_{S1}|≥ϵ]$?

I didn't really think of decomposing that term... his decomposition of the term was crucial for what he achieved.

Comment: @Learning...: The simplest answer is "experience", I guess; arguments like this are pretty standard, and once you have seen them a few times, they start to seem like a natural way to proceed.